# picture box coming above MDI child form

Tags: c#

I have 1 MDI form on which there are 2 picture box , when I am opening child form it goes behind the picture box. Here is the code for opening child form

```
private void schoolToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            classSetup cs = new classSetup();
            cs.MdiParent = this;
            cs.Show();
            cs.BringToFront();
        }
```

I am using C# 2008

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal for an MDI Container form.

You use an MDI *(Multiple Document Interface)* form to display multiple child windows together, while keeping them confined to the boundaries of the MDI form. You should not be placing controls directly on the MDI form, other than perhaps something that applies to the entire application, like a menu bar or a status bar.

Move the `PictureBox` controls into their own form, and display that form when you need them.

---

To display your image as a banner, add a `PictureBox` and set the `Dock` property to `Top`. Any forms you add to the MDI container should display under it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer but I want to display this image always as a banner, how to do this?